# Change Microsoft Bot 4.0 Channel

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a web service that will contact my bot over default web http and provide user contact information + endpoint. This service is basically a job scheduler for the bot. I then want to use that information to have the bot contact the user on one of several custom direct line channels depending on the endpoint sent down from the service.

The idea is that each provider has their own API to communicate with the user.
The service will determine which provider API the bot should use and the conversation will continue through that channel.

[image]

Is it possible to switch channels like this? I've always just kept the communication on the same channel and never passed it off. Is there a 4.0 example I can reference?

Comment: Can you include more specific questions you have about the switching of channels?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I've updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Although I voted to reopen, I can see why this was put on hold; it's a bit broad vs. the preferred SO question: "here's my code, help me fix it". That being said, sounds to me like you'd be helped with [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore) and [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), both about proactive messaging.

Comment: The basic concept would be 1) have the user interact with the bot from each endpoint, 2) save a `conversationReference` of each interaction, 3) call the appropriate `conversationReference` to proactively message the user, as needed.